# A subspace of $\ell_2$ of infinite codimension

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The set $S^*$ of all sequences with finitely many non-zero coordinates is a subset of $\ell_2$. I know that codim$_{\ell_2}S^*=\infty$. But how do I show that?

I tried to find an infinite basis $B$ of $\ell_2$ such that all sets $b+S^*$ (for all $b \in B$) are also a basis. This does not work for the basis $e_1=(1,0,\dots),e_2=(0,1,0,\dots),\dots $ because $e_i +S^*=S^*$ for all $i$, and I could not find any other basis for $\ell_2$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}S^*=\aleph_0$.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. I'll arrange my thoughts and hopefully I will post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems right to me, except of course that taking the canonical basis $\{e_k\}$ won't work since $e_k=e_j$ in the quotient space.

Try instead the following:

starting an appropiate $v\in\ell^2\setminus S^*$, consider the forward shift 
$F(v_1,v2,\dots)=(0,v_1,v_2,\dots)$. If $v$ is properly chosen (not hard to find), the collection of orbits $\{F^n(v)\}$ will give you an infinite linear independent set of the quotient space.